# cpp application to fetch Bluetooth devices informaton

Tags: c++, bluetooth

I want to create a c++ application that fetch information about paired and visible blue tooth devices to a system. I want to implement this using windows api. I don't want to use winsocket program, which already I have.Thanks in advance

Comment: On Windows platform all Bluetooth communication (classic) is implemented through WinSock. It does not matter what you want, it is how it is. Some parts implemented through Win Bluetooth API. Or use thrid-party libs.

Comment: Thanks for the information..But I just need to get the data like what and all bluetooth devices are visible and which are connected, their connection status..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothgetdeviceinfo

Comment: About visible: there is no easy way to get list of only devices that are discoverable *visible in your terms). You can get list of all paired and/or discoverable devices only. That means that if device is paired but not visible you will get this device in the list any way. So you have to ping each paired device somehow to make sure that the device is really available.